# Node.js Mongo Unhandled error EADDRINUSE :::5000

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting this error, probably, from the backend of my MERN application, and I don't know how to deal with it and what exaclty the error is:

```
events.js:167
[0]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[0]       ^
[0]
[0] Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5000
[0]     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1336:14)
[0]     at listenInCluster (net.js:1384:12)
[0]     at Server.listen (net.js:1471:7)
[0]     at Function.listen (/Users/robertosannazzaro/Desktop/Coding/crud_fabrizio/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
[0]     at MongoClient.connect (/Users/robertosannazzaro/Desktop/Coding/crud_fabrizio/server.js:19:9)
[0]     at result (/Users/robertosannazzaro/Desktop/Coding/crud_fabrizio/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:414:17)
[0]     at executeCallback (/Users/robertosannazzaro/Desktop/Coding/crud_fabrizio/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:406:9)
[0]     at err (/Users/robertosannazzaro/Desktop/Coding/crud_fabrizio/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:286:5)

[0]     at connectCallback (/Users/robertosannazzaro/Desktop/Coding/crud_fabrizio/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:241:5)
[0]     at process.nextTick (/Users/robertosannazzaro/Desktop/Coding/crud_fabrizio/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:463:7)
[0] Emitted 'error' event at:
[0]     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1363:8)
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get rid of this? This error doesn't happen always, only after refreshing my app and when I perform in my front end a GET requests to my backend.
I tried to catch any error in the frondend by doing this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.setState({
      curTime: new Date().toLocaleString()
    });
  }, 1000);
  axios.get("http://localhost:5000/").then((res, err) => {
    if (!err) {
      this.setState({ notes: res });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```

But the error still happens, I believe it probably comes from the backend, where I connect to the database.

Comment: First you must test your backend, perform test on the routes that your frontend uses, use postman or insomnia to execute the routes or build the same tests of your routes, functional test and unit tests.

Comment: As @JustCase suggest, debug your backend, why the process keep on restarting everytime when you make request to your backend. If it happens only one time, just use killall -9 node. It will kill all the node provcess.

Comment: I seems that after doing `killall -9 node` it does not appear anymore. Should I investigate further why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you something else is already listening on `::` (any IPv6), port 5000. Maybe you have another (older?) instance of the backend running on your machine.
Stop whatever is listening on port 5000 and your error should go away (until your forget again).